# ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined at Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, local-storage

I am using local storage to save the updatet variable value every time I run my test case but fore some reasons I get the error:

> ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined at Object ReferenceError:
> localStorage is not defined at Object.
> (/app/Projects/Javascript/Mocha/27403_9907/Libraries/addNewBeneficiary.js:17:49)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14) at
> Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32) at
> Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12) at
> Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) at require
> (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18) at Object.
> (/app/Projects/Javascript/Mocha/27403_9907/run/test.js:13:39) at
> Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14) at
> Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32) at
> Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12) at
> ModuleWrap. (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:199:29) at
> ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:183:25) at async
> Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:178:24) at async
> formattedImport
> (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:7:14) at async
> Object.exports.requireOrImport
> (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:48:32) at async
> Object.exports.loadFilesAsync
> (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:88:20) at async
> singleRun (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:125:3)
> at async Object.exports.handler
> (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:374:5)

I have created a JS file and uploaded it in a customized platform called Momentum, which we use for automated test. the code file is as following:

```
const { wd } = require("../setup/v2setup");

                    var isStepFailed = false;

                    var assert = require('assert');
                    var should = require('should');
                    var windowSize = null;
                    const axios = require('axios').default;

let storedXPathIndex = localStorage.getItem("storedXPathIndex");
                    let xPathIndex = (storedXPathIndex) ? ++storedXPathIndex : 0;
                    localStorage.setItem("storedXPathIndex", xPathIndex);
                    const max = 5;

                    exports.setAddNewBeneficiaryMethods = (driver) =>{

wd.addPromiseChainMethod('SelectAcc', () => {


                    
   if( ++xPathIndex > max ) xPathIndex = 0;
    return 

driver.swipeUntilElement("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.ScrollView/android.view.ViewGroup/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.view.ViewGroup["+ xPathIndex +"]")
})
}
```

I also tried a mock function as suggested below and now i get

> window is not defined

the mock function and how I am calling it is

```
function storageMock() {
let storage = {};

return {
  setItem: function(key, value) {
    storage[key] = value || '';
  },
  getItem: function(key) {
    return key in storage ? storage[key] : null;
  },
  removeItem: function(key) {
    delete storage[key];
  },
  get length() {
    return Object.keys(storage).length;
  },
  key: function(i) {
    const keys = Object.keys(storage);
    return keys[i] || null;
  }
}
  }

wd.addPromiseChainMethod('SelectAcc', () => {

 let storedXPathIndex = window.localStorage.getItem("storedXPathIndex");
                let xPathIndex = (storedXPathIndex) ? ++storedXPathIndex : 0;
                window.localStorage.setItem("storedXPathIndex", xPathIndex);
```

Not sure where am I doing wrong
const max = 5;

```
   if( ++xPathIndex > max ) xPathIndex = 0;
    return 

driver.swipeUntilElement("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.ScrollView/android.view.ViewGroup/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.view.ViewGroup["+ xPathIndex +"]")
})
```

Comment: [`localStorage` is on the web](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) not in Node.JS. Unless you have some extra library that adds it, however, I'd expect you to import it, if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

localStorage is only available in browsers, So if you want to run tests, you need to mock the object as explained in this answer about [how to use `localStorage` in tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26177872/3630448), but here is a peek:

```
function storageMock() {
    let storage = {};

    return {
      setItem: function(key, value) {
        storage[key] = value || '';
      },
      getItem: function(key) {
        return key in storage ? storage[key] : null;
      },
      removeItem: function(key) {
        delete storage[key];
      },
      get length() {
        return Object.keys(storage).length;
      },
      key: function(i) {
        const keys = Object.keys(storage);
        return keys[i] || null;
      }
    };
  }

// mock the localStorage
window.localStorage = storageMock();
```

Comment: i updated my question, with the mock you suggested but now i am getting the error "window is not defined". Maybe you can take a look and have any suggestion? @Farzin Farzanehnia

Comment: Well that was just to explain, I don't see where you use `storageMock()` but before your tests run make sure to do something like `const localStorage = storageMock()` and that should work.